# Designing a nice form with a predefined width for both the label and the text field

Tags: html, css

I want to design a nice form for my webpage, which I want to resemble something like this. [image]

---

Basically, I want that the text describing the input field as well as the input fields have some predefined width. I am not using a table layout for my forms, instead I am using the *label for* approach.

What happens is something like this

[image]

---

I can set the size for the text field as I have done. I don't know how to deal with setting a width for the text or the label. The html goes something like this:

```
<form class="myform" method="POST" action="./php/prescribe.php">
        <label for="fname">First Name :</label>
        <input type="password" name="fname" size="35"><br>

        <label for="fname">Give your email address :</label>
        <input type="password" name="lname" size="35"><br>

        <label for="fname">First Name :</label>
        <input type="password" name="fname" size="35"><br>

        <label for="fname">First Name :</label>
        <input type="password" name="fname" size="35"><br>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could float the labels:

```
.myform label {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  width: 12em; /* or whatever */
}
```

Floats can be a little irritating because old IE versions sometimes do stupid things.

Or you could use `display: inline-block`, which I prefer:

```
.myform label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 12em; /* or whatever */
}
```

With that, you'd need to add `<br>` elements between the inputs, which some might consider unpleasant.

Another alternative would be to use a `<dl>` block for the whole thing, though that really doesn't change the basic problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use CSS.  Also, you would want to use a wrapper around each row.  Here's a quick and dirty example.

CSS:

```
.form-row{}
.form-row-alt {} /* add alternating color here */
.form-row label, .form-row-alt label { display: inline-block; width: 150px; }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="form-row">
    <label>First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" />
</div>
```

Comment: No problem!  In a case like this, it might be easier to have a separate class for the "alt" case, so that you wouldn't need the comma selector. Then to style the alternate rows you'd have a `.form-row.alt` rule. I think even IE7 can do that :-)